# Node.js is giving different HTTP responses with different timeouts

Tags: javascript, node.js, httpresponse

I'm using `Node.js` for backend (I'm just testing it with `localhost`), and I noticed that with this code...

```
response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
fs.readFile('index.html', (_err, data) => {
    response.end(data);
});


response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
const responseBody = { headers, method, url, body };
response.write(JSON.stringify(responseBody));
response.end();
```

...the second `response.end()` call was "overwriting" the first one (the `html` page was never shown).

---

So I decided to use `setTimeout` to see if I could make appear the content of `index.html` first, and then after a few seconds the `application/json` response...

```
setTimeout(() => {
    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
    const responseBody = { headers, method, url, body };
    response.write(JSON.stringify(responseBody));
    response.end();
}, 1000);
```

...but after the first `response.end()` call I could never see the `json` appear.

---

Then I had a strange idea, I decided to change the timeout from `1000ms` to `1ms`, and the `html` content was never shown, I immediately (or maybe after `1ms`, which is such a small amount of time) saw the `json` content.

I tried with `10ms` but it worked as with `1000ms`, then I tried with `2ms`, and refreshing the page it sometimes showed `json` and sometimes `html`.

---

How is this possible? The `response.end()` function doesn't wait until the `response` has ended? Is it caused by something else? Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to achieve here. You cannot write two different responses on the same connection.

Comment: "*How is this possible? The response.end() function doesn't wait until the response has ended?*" - No (or maybe, but irrelevant). What doesn't wait in your code is the **asynchronous** `fs.readFile(…)` call.

Comment: @Bergi, I know, it was just a try and I was surprised by the fact that one response.end() was overwriting the other one.

Comment: Oh, ok, so @Bergi if the timeout is less than the time taken to read the index.html file the second `response.end()` call will be called first?

Comment: It's more like "preventing the other one from having any effect".
Because after one calls `end`, whatever the other one tried to send, it won't be sent.

Comment: @qrsngky I really wonder why that doesn't throw an exception, like "response is already written" or "stream is already closed".

Comment: @Bergi honestly, I don't know, but it's really up to the designers.
This contrasts with when you try to set header after the response is already written, it gives "Error: Can't set headers after they are sent to the client".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're correct in saying that `response.end()` does not wait until file transfer is actually ended.

I actually learned that while using express:
If you do `response.sendFile(...)` followed by `response.end()` in the same function, then no actual file is sent (the response is 'closed' before the file can actually be sent), it just gives an empty response.

---

## Edit:

In your first code, the JSON writing is always executed earlier than the `readFile` callback. (The readFile callback is having an `asynchronous` behavior.)

---

But once you have the timeout, there is a race between the "timeout callback" and "readFile callback".

Since file loading times can vary, it may be sometimes faster than the timeout and sometimes slower. But whichever callback 'wins the race', it will call the `response.end()`, **preventing the other one from sending anything**.

Comment: So response's methods have an asynchronous behaviour?

Comment: Yes, I think it's designed that way. Otherwise, the server would have to stop doing anything other than loading the entire file. 
From the user's perspective, it's almost like the server 'hangs'.

Comment: Ok, thanks, but the problem here isn't due to a response ending too early, but to a response not really ending, since there's an other `response.end()` call after a few lines and it really ends the response.

Comment: @FLAK-ZOSO In your first code, the JSON writing is always executed earlier than the `readFile` callback. (The `readFile` callback is having an asynchronous behavior.)

But once you have the timeout, there is a race between the "timeout callback" and "readFile callback". Since file loading times can vary, it may be sometimes faster than the timeout and sometimes slower. But whichever callback 'wins the race', it will call the `response.end`, preventing the other one from sending anything.

Comment: This is exactly the answer I was searching for, if you could write it in your answer I'll accept it, thank you 

Comment: @FLAK-ZOSO alright

Answer (score 1):

When you use setTimeout, the code you're timing out, is pushed to the "end" of the execution stack, and normal program execution resumes.

In this case sending the response and everything that would happen if you'd straight out delete the code there.

Comment: Yes, but why do different things happen when timeout is changed from 1ms to 2ms?

Comment: 1ms is an eterntity in cpu time. A lot of things happen in that time. Imagine if only one instruction would happen in one nano second, then in one millisecond, 1 000 000 instructions will have occurred. In 2 milliseconds 2 000 000 before your script kicks in. There is a lot that can happen in that time for code.(for comparison, that would mean a cpu running at 1 Mhz or something near there...  Last released the RISC-I in 1982 ran that fast at max speed, in reality your script will run many more instructions on your Ghz beast)